# Correct way of updating __repr__ in Python using dataclasses and inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-dataclasses, repr

I have the following code:

```py
from dataclasses import MISSING, asdict, dataclass
from typing import Any
from datetime import datetime


@dataclass()
class BookMetadata():
    '''Parent class.'''
    
    isbn: str 
    title: str 
    author: str
    publisher: str
    date_published: int
    
    
    def format_time(self, unix: int) -> str:
        '''Convert unix time to %Y-%m-%d.'''
        
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(int(str(unix)[0:10])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    

    def __post_init__(self):
        '''Change attributes after assignment.'''
            
        # Change date from UNIX to YYYY-MM-DD
        self.date_published = self.format_time(self.date_published)
      

@dataclass()
class RetailPrice(BookMetadata):
    '''Child class.'''
    
    def __init__(self, 
                 isbn, title, author, publisher, date_published,
                 price_usd, price_aud, price_eur, price_gbp) -> None:

        self.price_usd: float = price_usd
        self.price_aud: float = price_aud
        self.price_eur: float = price_eur
        self.price_gbp: float = price_gbp
        
        BookMetadata.__init__(self, isbn, title, author, publisher, date_published)
        # Or: super(RetailPrice, self).__init__(isbn, title, author, publisher, date_published)
        
        
    def stringify(self, obj: Any) -> str:
        '''Turn object into string.'''
        
        return str(obj)
        
        
    def __post_init__(self):
        '''Change attribute values after assignment.'''
        self.price_usd = self.stringify(self.price_usd)
        

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        '''Update representation including parent and child class attributes.'''
        
        return f'Retailprice(isbn={super().isbn}, title={super().title}, author={super().author}, publisher={super().publisher}, date_published={super().date_published}, price_usd={self.price_usd}, price_aud={self.price_aud}, price_eur={self.price_eur}, price_gbp={self.price_gbp})'
```

My `__repr__` method is failing with the following message:
`AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'isbn'`, so I am referencing the attributes of the parent class all wrong here.

As it's possible to call the parent dataclass under the `__init__` method of the child dataclass, (`BookMetadata.__init__(self, isbn, title, author, publisher, date_published)`), I thought that trying with `super(BookMetadata, self)` would work, but it failed with the same message.

How should I reference the attributes of the parent class in `__repr__` within the child dataclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with that code. The field values are inconsistent with their declared types, the use of `int(str(unix)[0:10])` is bizarre and likely to lead to wrong dates, `RetailPrice` largely abandons the use of dataclass fields in favor of writing out a bunch of `__init__` arguments manually...

We'll go over this in two parts. One that just fixes the immediate issues, and one that shows what this *should* look like.

---

#### Part 1: Fixing the immediate issues.

For the `__repr__` method, the most immediate issue is the attempt to access instance attributes through `super()`. Attributes don't work that way. An instance doesn't have separate "superclass attributes" and "child attributes"; it just has attributes, and they're all accessed through `self`, regardless of what class they were set in.

Your instance already has all the attributes you need. Contrary to your self-answer, you don't need to (and absolutely shouldn't) call `super().__init__` or `super().__post_init__` inside `__repr__` to make the attributes available. You can just access them:

```
def __repr__(self) -> str:
    return f'RetailPrice(isbn={self.isbn}, title={self.title}, author={self.author}, publisher={self.publisher}, date_published={self.date_published}, price_usd={self.price_usd}, price_aud={self.price_aud}, price_eur={self.price_eur}, price_gbp={self.price_gbp})'
```

You'll see `date_published` as a Unix timestamp instead of a YYYY-MM-DD string, but that's because your subclass's `__post_init__` doesn't call the superclass's `__post_init__`. Fix that:

```
def __post_init__(self):
    super().__post_init__()
    self.price_usd = self.stringify(self.price_usd)
```

and your `__repr__` output will be okay.

---

#### Part 2: How the code should really be written.

You didn't need to write your own `__repr__`. That's one of the things that the `@dataclass` decorator is designed to handle for you. You didn't let `@dataclass` do its job, though. Instead of declaring fields and letting `@dataclass` generate code based on the fields, you wrote things manually.

If you just declared fields:

```
@dataclass
class BookWithRetailPrice(BookMetadata):
    price_usd: float
    price_aud: float
    price_eur: float
    price_gbp: float
```

`@dataclass` could have handled almost everything, generating a sensible `__repr__`, as well as `__eq__` and `__hash__`.

I left out the part about stringifying `price_usd`, because that was weird, inconsistent with the other price fields, and inconsistent with the declared type of `price_usd`. You can do it in `__post_init__` if you really want, but it's a bad idea.

Similarly, converting `date_published` to a YYYY-MM-DD string when the field is declared as an int is a bad idea. If you want a YYYY-MM-DD string, a property would probably make more sense:

```
@dataclass
class BookMetadata:
    isbn: str 
    title: str 
    author: str
    publisher: str
    publication_timestamp: int

    @property
    def publication_date_string(self):
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(self.publication_timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

You'll note that with the `@dataclass`-generated `__repr__`, you'll see quotation marks around the values of string fields, like `title`. The generated `__repr__` uses the `__repr__` of field values, instead of calling `str` on fields. This is useful for reducing ambiguity, especially if any of the field values have commas in them. Unless you have a really strong reason to do otherwise, you should let `@dataclass` write `__repr__` that way.

Comment: This is very useful, but the reason for not letting the dataclass "do its job" is because it was not really clear from the docs how to implement inheritance with dataclasses. When initialising the child class, how else would one access the parent attributes and add to them, if not by using an init method?

Answer (score -1):

This was actually simpler than I thought. All it takes is to add a `__repr__` method to the child dataclass class, within which two calls to the parent dataclass are made:

- `super().__init__(...)` to make the parent attributes accessible
- `super().__post_init__()` to make visible the parent attributes modified after assignment

The complete working example is as follows:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any
from datetime import datetime


@dataclass()
class BookMetadata():
    '''Parent class.'''
    
    isbn: str 
    title: str 
    author: str
    publisher: str
    date_published: int
    
    
    def format_time(self, unix: int) -> str:
        '''Convert unix time to %Y-%m-%d.'''
        
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(int(str(unix)[0:10])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    

    def __post_init__(self):
        '''Change attributes after assignment.'''
            
        # Change date from UNIX to YYYY-MM-DD
        self.date_published = self.format_time(self.date_published)
      

@dataclass()
class RetailPrice(BookMetadata):
    '''Child class.'''
    
    def __init__(self, 
                 isbn, title, author, publisher, date_published,
                 price_usd, price_aud, price_eur, price_gbp) -> None:

        self.price_usd: float = price_usd
        self.price_aud: float = price_aud
        self.price_eur: float = price_eur
        self.price_gbp: float = price_gbp
        
        BookMetadata.__init__(self, isbn, title, author, publisher, date_published)
        # Or: super(RetailPrice, self).__init__(isbn, title, author, publisher, date_published)
        
        
    def stringify(self, obj: Any) -> str:
        '''Turn object into string.'''
        
        return str(obj)
        
        
    def __post_init__(self):
        '''Change attribute values after assignment.'''
        self.price_usd = self.stringify(self.price_usd)


    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        '''Update representation including parent and child class attributes.'''
        
        super().__init__(self.isbn, self.title, self.author, self.publisher, self.date_published)
        super().__post_init__()
        
        return f'RetailPrice(isbn={self.isbn}, title={self.title}, author={self.author}, publisher={self.publisher}, date_published={self.date_published}, price_usd={self.price_usd}, price_aud={self.price_aud}, price_eur={self.price_eur}, price_gbp={self.price_gbp})'
```

The output is now:

```
RetailPrice(isbn=1234-5678-9000, title=My book, author=Name Surname, publisher=My publisher, date_published=2022-12-08, price_usd=17.99, price_aud=23.99, price_eur=15.99, price_gbp=16.99)
```